Grok Parser unable to setup rules
I have an application that logs voip call data. Im trying to extract the data into useable json as well as make it searchable in datadog using some of the key fields. below is a sample of the log data which I would like to "read" (obviously obfuscated for security)
CCX00013180/servername.mydomaiun.local/2024.10.30.08.36.29.477/1:ea1e78d9eb8aee5b9bdddccbd648ad68:0:1/00000012/Line-5226e1eff2957d5a3afad6fc74d81cb0/Call Summary: status=success direction=out calledid=tel:+27841234567 callerid=27231231231 start=2024.10.30.08.36.13.475 end=2024.10.30.08.36.29.477 duration=16002
From this I require a result as per below
{ "date": "2024.10.30.08.36.29.477", "sessionid": "ea1e78d9eb8aee5b9bdddccbd648ad68", "Call_Summary": { "status": "success", "direction": "out", "calledid": "27841234567", "callerid": "27231231231", "start": "2024.10.30.08.36.13.475", "end": "2024.10.30.08.36.29.477", "duration": 16002" } "server": "servername.mydomaiun.local", "line": "5226e1eff2957d5a3afad6fc74d81cb0", "token": "CCX00013180" }
I tried the below rule
logdata %{data::csv("token,server,date,sessiondata,val,line,call","/")}
this managed to split it for me everywhere there is a slash but then I cant seem to figure out how to further split the values such as the value from sessiondata needs the leading 1: and trailing ":0:1" removed, val I dont need, line needs to just be the key value without the Line- prefix and call I would like it to also be split into values as call summary
I also tried %{data:call_summary:keyvalue} which did a great job on all of the call data but then I cant seem to get it to work in conjunction with the other important data such as token, server etc
I also tried following the datadog sample to sort of type the sentance and where you need values simple do something like %{data::keyvalue} but because of the / being used as a seperator it does not work or thats what i believe the issue to be.
The logging is done by the application and there is no way to change how it logs so I'm stuck with the structure as is
